# What are the return parameters from jQuery .ajax with dataType json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following:

```
    var row = 99;
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/Admin/" + obj.table + "s/JsonUpdate",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { PartitionKey: pk,
                RowKey: rk,
                Entity: entity,
                Field: type, 
                Value: val }
    })
    .done(updateFieldDone(json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, row))
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    });
```

But I am confused about what exactly is returned with .done. Is it okay to code updateFieldDone(json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, row) like this. Previously i just had updateFieldDone() but the problem I have is that I need to pass a parameter called row. How can I do that?

Comment: can you not determine the row parameter from the element that is firing the AJAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `context` parameter to pass additional data to the success callback:

```
var row = 99;
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/" + obj.table + "s/JsonUpdate",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    context: { row: row },
    data: { 
        PartitionKey: pk,
        RowKey: rk,
        Entity: entity,
        Field: type, 
        Value: val 
    }
})
.done(function(json) {
    // Here "this" will represent the object we passed as context
    var row = this.row;
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

or if you want it in a separate function:

```
var row = 99;
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/" + obj.table + "s/JsonUpdate",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    context: { row: row },
    data: { 
        PartitionKey: pk,
        RowKey: rk,
        Entity: entity,
        Field: type, 
        Value: val 
    }
})
.done(updateFieldDone)
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

and then define the function:

```
function updateFieldDone(json) {
    // Here "this" will represent the object we passed as context
    var row = this.row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I have never heard of context and that's exactly what I need. For the updateFieldDone am I correct in saying there is just the one parameter passed?

Comment: No, actually there are also 2 other parameters: the status and the jqXHR object but we usually don't care about them and do not include them in the signature.